# How to prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{x^2}{e^x}=0$?

Tags: limits, infinity

I need to prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{x^2}{e^x}=0$.

Comment: Are you allowed to use l'Hôpital's theorem?

Comment: Do you know about l'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Do you know that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{e^x}=0$?

Comment: @Ritz Not yet...

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the well-known inequality $e^t\ge 1+t$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$.
Therefore $$e^x=(e^{x/3})^3\ge \left(1+\frac x3\right)^3=1+x+\frac13x^2+\frac1{27}x^3$$ for $x\ge 0$, whence
$$0\le\frac{x^2}{e^x}\le \frac{x^2}{1+x+\frac13x^2+\frac1{27}x^3}\to 0.$$

Answer (score 7):

$$0 \leq \frac{x^2}{e^x}= \frac{x^2}{(e^{x/4})^4}\leq \left(\frac{x}{(1+x/4)^2}\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

For $x>0$, we have $e^x \geq \dfrac{x^3}{3!}$ (Taylor expansion of $e^x$). Hence, we have
$$\dfrac{x^2}{e^x} \leq \dfrac{6}x \to 0 \text{ as }x \to \infty$$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know much about Taylor expansion... yet